# Is there an option for rounding rectangles manually in Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, illustrator-effects

[image]

I am using Illustrator CS6 and when I want to make a rectangle's corners round by using the direct selection tool and doing it manually, there is no option for that. So how to do so?

Comment: I believe the `Live corners` are a CC feature.

Answer (score 4):

[Live Corners](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-with-live-corners.html) and [Live Shapes](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-with-live-corners.html) were new features added in CC so aren't available in CS6.

What you can do is use a "Round Corners" effect:

> *Effects → Stylize → Round Corners...*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since this functionality was not made available until later versions of illustrator, your only option is to do it through a plugin:

- [VectorScribe](http://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/), from AstuteGraphics has not only live (rounded)
  corners, but TONS of functionality to edit paths. It is a must for
  all serious AI users.
- [XtreamPath](http://www.cvalley.com/products/xtreampath/movies/) is also a multi-function plugin that has rounded
  corners by dragging.

Comment: The reality is even with CC+, VectorScribe *still* handles this better than the built in Adobe functions.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

I am using Illustrator CS5. I always do it like this. Then if I need to adjust further I use the Direct Selection tool and adjust it.